# Custom live template does not show up in xhtml JSF file

Tags: intellij-idea, live-templates

I am using IntelliJ 2017.2 ultimate edition and I have created a live template to surround text in xhtml (JSF) by a tag and attribute.

```
#{myvalue}
```

should become

```
<h:outputText value="#{myvalue}" />
```

I created a live template named "swot" applicable to in XML : XML Text.

```
<h:outputText value="$SELECTION$" />
```

Unfortunately, it does not show up when I try to surround a selection in a xhtml file. I only get standard live templates.

[image: Live template surround with completion]

### Update with solution

As the file in which I want to applicate the template is JSF xhtml file, I just had to applicate it to "JSP"

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the file in which I want to applicate the template is JSF xhtml file, I just had to applicate it to "JSP"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Setting the applicability to HTML should solve your issue. Please see below image:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the insight Actually my file was JSF xhtml file so I just had to applicate te template to "JSP"